# how to convert ASCII "NULL" into plain text?

Tags: sql, text, ansi-sql

I have a file that is generated from legacy system in ANSI format.  In the header of this file a row contains the value NULL

I want to query a SQL database and generate the same file.  Everything works correctly expect for the Null value in the header field.  When SQL generates the text file it changes the Null character to blank.

Here is a sample of that original file looks like
[image]

The output from the SQL file looks like this, with the Null being replaced with a blank, i need to find a way to render the Null from SQL into this text file.[image]

Comment: Plain text? What's the expected result?

Comment: Use `COALESCE(NULL, 'replacement')` to replace `NULL`values with whatever you want.

Comment: I think there's confusion between the ASCII character `NUL` (character-code 0) used in the escape-sequences above and `NULL` (used in SQL and C/C++ to [roughly] mean "no value"). Not sure how to make SQL stop converting it to a space though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a unique character or a string to represent NULL values while generating and replace those with NULL values afterwards.